# Синонимизировать [sqlitedatabase] и [sqlite]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Проголосуйте за [синонимизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/synonyms) пожалуйста, а то этот тег - тоже самое, что и [sqlitedatabase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlitedatabase).

Comment: утвердил синоним

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо)

Comment: @PashaPash модераторов тоже короткие ответы движок в комментарии переводит?

Comment: @PashaPash можете как ответ опубликовать, чтоб я уже зааксептил его? Напишите пару предложений, как вы доблестно это делали, чтобы автоматом в комментарий не перевелось =D

Comment: @Suvitruf требует 30 символов :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделано (уже давно). Утвердил синоним.